# How could i see the space is separable?

Tags: general-topology

Here is a result from Husek in 1977 in the Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology, Kunen, Vaughan, P102~103[image]:

Let $X$ be compact $T_2$ with a small diagonal and $t(X)\le \omega$, then $X$ is metrizable.
To see this, he first proved such space is separable. Why $Z$ is closed in $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Z$ is closed in $X$ because $X$ is countably tight.  This implies that $\overline{Y} = \bigcup \{ \overline{A} : A \subseteq Y \text{ is countable} \}$, and every countable subset of $Z$ is a subset of some $Y_\alpha$, so in fact $\overline{Y} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \omega_1} \overline{Y_\alpha} = Z$.

Comment: @Paul:  While we do have that, it is not necessary to show that to conclude that $Z$ is closed; we just need it to be the closure of aome set, and $Y$ was easier to demonstrate.